# Encoding an Underscore to %5F

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode to encode an underscore to %5f, but the encoded value does not give me the hex representation. How will I accomplish this?

```
string encodedValue = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("First_Name");
```

The value I want in the encodedValue string is "First%5FName".

Is there something I am missing? I have also tried using the HttpUtility.UrlEncode, but that does not give me the desired result as well.

I know this should be something simple, but I cant get around it.

Comment: What *does* this give you?

Comment: You are thinking of `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.  But that won't do it either as `_` is not a reserved character in either HTML or URLs.   So most standard utilities will not encode it with their encode methods.

Comment: here is the reference for DMoses' statement http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: @MUG4N: RFC1738 is ancient. The current standard is [RFC3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). [Section 2.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.3) lists the unreserved characters, including underscore.

Comment: that's weird, if you look at the link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp it underscores are represented by a %5f

Comment: @KingCronus it gives me the exact same value "First_Name"

Comment: w3schools may be improving, but a lot of their "information" is still faulty and the site should certainly not be taken as a repository of fact - just reference. Find definite information elsewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you just want to replace `_` with `%5f`, you can just use `myString.Replace("_", "%5f");`

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it. So I will mark this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old subject but to convert a char in its HexEscape format you should use:

```
myString.Replace("_", Uri.HexEscape("_"));
```